# Keep PHP's output with tee -a

Tags: terminal, php, stdout, tee

Normally when running PHP script in web server mode, this would show up:

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:12345
PHP 5.6.1 Development Server started at Mon Nov 24 14:09:22 2014
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:12345
Document root is /tmp
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But when that command appended with `| tee -a accesss.log`, that output is missing:

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:12345 | tee -a access.log
# blank
```

What should I do to keep that output shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [GNU stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html), you can use:

```
$ stdbuf -o0 -e0 php -S 0.0.0.0:12345 | tee -a access.log
PHP 5.4.34-0+deb7u1 Development Server started at Mon Nov 24 14:38:33 2014
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:12345
Document root is /home/cuonglm
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```